# saltstack dynamically update etc hosts

Tags: salt-stack, configuration-management

How to dynamically update /etc/hosts file with saltstack.

There is example that works with ansible great, but don't know how to do it with salt.

http://xmeblog.blogspot.fr/2013/06/ansible-dynamicaly-update-etchosts.html

```
  - name: add hostname in /etc/hosts
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts regexp='.*{{ item }}$' line="{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{item}}" state=present
    when: hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] is defined
    with_items: groups['all']
```

This will update /etc/hosts with all ansible hosts-ip and host address available in inventory file.

How it is possible with salt? 
I want to collect all minions ip address and hostname and update it on all minions /etc/hosts.

```
minion1 => ip (192.168.1.1) hostname is (example1.net)
minion2 => ip (192.168.1.2) hostname is (example2.net)
minion3 => ip (192.168.1.3) hostname is (example3.net)
```

In all minions /etc/hosts file entry should be like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
192.168.1.1  example1.net
192.168.1.2  example2.net
192.168.1.3  example3.net
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look into https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/hostsfile-formula, hopefully it suits your needs.

This particular formula allows to 'automagically' create `/etc/hosts` records for all known minions.

Please no, I've noticed the formula link to Formula Documentation has been broken, try this one instead [Salt Formulas installation and usage instructions.](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html)

---

[Salt Formulas explained](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html)

> Formulas are pre-written Salt States. They are as open-ended as Salt States themselves and can be used for tasks such as installing a package, configuring and starting a service, setting up users or permissions, and many other common tasks.